# How to do something n times per second?

Tags: java, performance

Suppose you had to perform a task with a requirement of doing it fixed number of times (say `20,000`) per second.

How would you time the event?

Comment: Give your task to a `ScheduledExecutorService` to execute.

Comment: We would need a little more info. What happens when task `n` overruns? Run two tasks concurrently or wait?

Comment: Do it 19,999 times a second and speed up slightly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I suggest you try it and see what happens. ;)

Comment: For this kind of requirement I'd take a look at QNX or another real-time OS.

Comment: Does each iteration of the task need to take 1/20000 of a second, or can you just run the task 20000 times and then wait for the entire second to have passed before beginning another set of 20000?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For 20K times per second you need to busy wait for the next interval.  I suggest wait until the next time it should have run to iron out the impact of jitter.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
long rate = 20000;
for(long i = 0; ; i++) {

   // do something

   long end = start + i * 1000000000L / rate;
   while(System.nanoTime() < end);
}
```

The reason you can't use built in Scheduler is that the minimum time slice is 100 micro-seconds which is 10K times per second and the minimum sleep time on many platforms is 1 milli-second.

Comment: On a non real time OS, it's almost impossible to achieve exactly the 20000 repetitions per second with this technique.

Comment: would it be beneficial in the while loop to Thread.yield()? Or would that potentially cause waiting too long because of not being scheduled in time(increase in "jitter" as you call it)?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo It's as close as you can get.  If you also isolate the CPU you will get less than 20 micro-second jitter.

Comment: @Cruncher The minimum time slice is 0.1 ms on many OSes and if you want a task every 0.05 ms you cannot afford to allow another thread to run.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So essentially, if you get context switched out, by the time you get back, you'll be behind by at least 2 iterations?

Comment: @Cruncher 2 if you are very lucky, I have seen jitter of 5 ms on an otherwise idle machine because the thread context switched (and the machine was not actually doing anything important and had 11 free CPUs)

Comment: @PeterLawrey, yeah I said 2 at the minimum based on your minimum time slice. As a follow-up, would it then make sense to allow the loop to "get ahead" by a few iterations, so that it doesn't get slammed in a context switch?

Answer (score 1):

If you're implementing a control system which requires fixed-interval execution and you want to implement it in Java, read up on [real-time Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/training/kp/j-kp-rtj/index.html).

If you just need something executed repeatedly and millisecond-granularity is sufficient, look at [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

If you need finer granularity (i.e., more than 1000 times per second) but you don't strictly require your code to execute at precise intervals, you may be able to get by with Peter Lawrey's busy-wait solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a perfect job for the [RateLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) from Guava.

**EDIT**

Had a glance into `RateLimiter`'s implemention - well, not an ideal candidate for a such a high rate, because to increment counter it uses synch-blocks and sleeps. But it should be fine if it is possible to change the granularity, i.e. split your `20.000` into `100` packs of `200` items each.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what are you doing in that task,for example if you are doing some networking ,where you are trying to do some connection it will depends on connection timeout and some other factors. If you are doing some basic operations you will be able to control the upper limit of operations ,for example maximum of 20 operations per second ,but you will never be able to control the lower limit because of other task that are running in pc.So it really depends on what are you doing,on whitch hardware you are running(specially procesor) and how bussy is that computer.